fetch() returns 404 error but calling multiple times gives the desired response
I'm new to react. In the provided code, I made a fetch request to the live API of Swiggy, it won't show any data on the screen, return a 404 and syntax error in the console that the return response is not a valid JSON as you can see in the screenshots, but the interesting thing is when I open the developer tools and refresh the page, it returns the response data with a 200 Ok status. What's happening here?


Code:

I tried to fetch the list of restaurants from swiggy's live API and expected to get the data but I get a 404 and syntax error on the console that return response is not a valid JSON token. when I open the chrome developer tools to check the potential errors and refresh the page once again, the API works perfectly and returns the list of restaurants. Why is this happening. I tried to search the cause and found that when developer tools are open, chrome loosens it's security and restrictions.
One Imp thing : I was previously getting the CORS error which is obvious. For that I downloaded a CORS bypass extension. I provided this info for context. Help me
